# (PYTHON) How to return all the words in the function? (instead of just one

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return

```
vowel = ('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u')
sentence = 'Write a script that encodes phrases'
def pig_latin(sentence):
    for words in sentence.split():
        if words[0] in vowel:
            words = words + 'ay'
        else: words = words[1:]+ words[0] + 'ay'
    return(words)
pig_latin(sentence)
```

I am trying to let this function print out all the words in the sentence but no matter where I place `return`, it always only gives me the first/ last word in the sentence. Can someone tell me what I did was wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You need to put some debugging `print` statements inside your loop.  The critical problem is that you are trying to use `words` for two conflicting purposes at the same time.  Each purpose destroys the other's progress.  Use one loop variable, and another to accumulate results.

Comment: @Evorage, you ok there?

Comment: wow thanks for being so friendly man

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to simply use an aggregator to build the string as you go:

```py
vowel = ('A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o','u')
sentence = 'Write a script that encodes phrases'
def pig_latin(sentence):
    aggregator = ''
    for words in sentence.split():
        if words[0] in vowel:
            words = words + 'ay'
        else: 
            words = words[1:]+ words[0] + 'ay'
        aggregator = aggregator + ' ' + words
   return aggregator
    
pig_latin(sentence)
```